# authentication facebook on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

With Angular 4 and typescript I have implemented Facebook authentication on firebase.

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();  
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
```

This works fine and after authentication in the local storage is created:

`firebase: authUser: AIzaSy .....`

and I see the user on the Firebase console.

But now the `firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()` returns undefined.

Comment: where is the console log statement for the token in your code?

Comment: test() {
    console.log('token ' + this.authService.getToken());
  }
when I call the method after authenticating with user and password it works

Comment: I understand the problem.
if we call the method after a few seconds it works

Comment: I think the solution is firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged.